# How To Remove HTML from React UL/LI

Tags: reactjs, loops

I have a `ul` being populated with `li`s in React and rendered to the DOM, but they show the HTML markup along with the content.

[image]

Example: `<strong>Wattage:</strong> 1100 Watts`

I've tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` at numerous points, but keep getting errors (the only resources online are straightforward implementations).

Here's the relevant code that handles the ul/li generation:

```
  getFeatureList = ((itemDescription) => {
    return itemDescription[0].features.map((feature, index) => (
      <li key={index}> { feature }</li>
    ))
  })

  render() {
    const itemDescription = this.state.data ? this.state.data.ItemDescription : null;
    const featureList = itemDescription ? this.getFeatureList(itemDescription) : null;

    return (
      <div className="product-highlights-container">
        <div className="product-highlights-title">product highlights</div>
        <ul className="product-features">
          {featureList}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

When I tried adding it in `getFeaturedList` around the `<li key...` I got an error. Additionally I tried to do `{ __html: {featuredList}` within the `ul` but had no luck.

Ultimately I'm trying to figure out what point to include it so the `li`s render without the  tags.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing any use of `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`... It would be great if you could post a [mcve]. You can probably use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to do so.

Comment: I mentioned where I tried implementing it, and that it didn't work.

Comment: But not how it didn't work. For instance, what error messages you received. The function works when used correctly. Please who know about how to get it to work might be able to get it working for you, but only if they know how you've used it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your `itemDescription` inside the `getFeatureList` is constructed like this:

```
itemDescription = [
  {
    features: [
      '<strong>Wattage Output:</strong> 1100 Watts',
      '<strong>Number of speeds:</strong> 3', // etc etc
    ]
  }
]
```

right? If it's not, please add a sample of the `itemDescription` data.

if that's the case, you should add

```
getFeatureList = ((itemDescription) => {
  return itemDescription[0].features.map((feature, index) => (
    <li key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: feature} />
  ))
})
```

Or you can use [react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html) library and use it like:

```
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

...
...

getFeatureList = ((itemDescription) => {
  return itemDescription[0].features.map((feature, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      {renderHTML(feature)}
    </li>
  ))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try to add that soon. I originally had react-render-html but I was getting module not found errors

Comment: module not found error shouldn't be appeared if you're properly installing the package via common method (npm install/yarn add), if you're experiencing that, please do include the error details and code where the error persists @James

Comment: if my answer is helpful please mark as accepted, @James. And if you're still having problems, feel free to add some comments :)

Comment: I'm getting `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"` with the code `<li key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: feature} />`